# Linking the Wso2 Api Manager to Wso2 ESB - 4.8.1 vice versa

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

Issue: we are not able to confiure the ESB proxy services in the WSO2 API Manager.. We are new this product..

WorkAround Solution explored: We have downloaded the Wso2 API (with version 1.9.0 ) Manager from WSO2 Website and We have started the Wso2 Api Manager and Both ESB and API Manager running successfully. In WSO2 ESB we have created the Proxy services and we want to setup the same in WSO2 Api Manager.
And JAVA Version we are using JDK 1.7 and please check the any version compatablity is there with WSO2 ESB and WSO2 Api manager .

Updated code:
    Please find the proxy service:

```
WSB PROXY SERVICE URL:https://I0025:8247/services/AddAssetService

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="AddAssetService"
       transports="https"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="enable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log>
            <property name="Message" value="testMessage"/>
         </log>
         <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <recipientlist>
                  <endpoint key="EkfAssetStoreEndPoint1"/>
                  <endpoint key="EkfAssetQueue_EndPoint"/>
               </recipientlist>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL uri="http://10.xx05.2.77:9765/services/AddAssetService?wsdl"/>
   <parameter name="ScenarioID">scenario1</parameter>
   <parameter name="serviceType">proxy</parameter>
   <enableSec/>
   <policy key="conf:/repository/axis2/service-groups/AddAssetService/services/AddAssetService/policies/UTOverTransport"/>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Could you please advise the same

Comment: It is really hard to understand your requrements. Do you want the same proxy to be deployed in APIM? Can you share the proxy xml here? Do you any execptions in the console?

Comment: Yes, I want to deploy the same proxy service in APIM

Comment: HI, I am aware of WSO2 ESB WSO2 MB,WSO2 DSS but i am not aware of the WSO2 APi Manager..

Comment: PLease find the below proxy service i have edited in the Question  and i want tpo deploy the same in hte APIM